# Encode Decode using python

Tags: python, character-encoding, decoding

I have this function in python

```
Str = "Ã¼";
print Str


def correctText( str ):
  str = str.upper()
  correctedText = str.decode('UTF8').encode('Windows-1252')
  return correctedText; 

corText = correctText(Str); 
print corText
```

It works and converts characters like Ã¼ and Ã© however it fails when i try Ã? and Â¶

Is there a way i can fix it?

Comment: Is that Python2 or Python3? If (as using `print` statement suggests) it's 2, how is your source file encoding declared?

Answer (score 0):

According to UTF8, Ã and Â¶ are not valid characters, meaning that don't have a number of bytes divisible by 4 (usually). What you need to do is either use some other kind of encoding or strip out errors in your str by using the unicode() function. I recommend using the ladder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know what kind of encoding those characters belong to ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to compose valid UTF-8 codes by several consecutive Windows-1252 codes.

For example, for `Ã¼`, the Windows-1252 code of `Ã` is `C3` and for `¼` it's `BC`. Together the code `C3BC` happens to be the UTF-8 code of `ü`.

Now, for `Ã?`, the Windows-1252 code is `C33F`, which is not a valid UTF-8 code (because the second byte does not start with `10`).

Are you sure this sequence occurs in your text? For example, for `à`, the Windows-1252 decoding of the UTF-8 code (C3A0) is `Ã` followed by a non-printable character (non-breaking space). So, if this second character is not printed, the `?` might be a regular character of the text.

For `Â¶` the Windows-1252 encoding is `C2B6`. Shouldn't it be `Ã¶`, for which the Windows-1252 encoding is `C3B6`, which equals the UTF-8 code of `ö`?